# TfidfVectorizer does not use the whole set of words in all documents?

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf

I am trying to build a TFIDF model with TfidfVectorizer. The feature name list namely the number of column of sparse matrix is shorter than the length of word set of documents even though I set min_df as 1. What happened?

Comment: Please show some code. This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the stop_words and max_features? If you provide values in either of these two, it will exclude some words.

Comment: Yes! I found out the problem is stop_words. There is a difference between removing stop_words from input of TfidfVectorizer and switching on stop_words option in TfidfVectorizer. Not sure why, but now the output is consistent with what I expected. Thanks.